# Number Validation not working in VBA

Tags: vba, validation, excel, numbers

I have a VBA script that is meant to take input on a product name, its quantity and price from a user (in a form) and, if everything passes validation then it should add it to the bottom of a table listing products.

Everything seems fine aside from the validation checking to see whether the quantity and price are numeric, it seemingly always go through this check.

Any help would be great. Thanks

I've copied my code below here:

```
Dim strName As String
Dim intResponse, intQuantity, intProdNumber As Integer
Dim intPrice As Currency
Dim wksInventory As Worksheet
Dim wksRange As Range
'Define Variables


Set wksInventory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)  'Set to correct worksheet
wksInventory.Select
wksInventory.Columns("A:D").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
wksInventory.Range("A2").Select



intProdNumber = 1

strName = txtProduct.Text                    'Assign strName to input in txtProduct text box
intQuantity = Val(txtQuantity.Text)          'Assign intQuantity to input in txtQuantity text box
intPrice = Val(txtPrice.Text)                'Assign intPrice to input in txtPrice text box



Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If intProdNumber <= Val(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        intProdNumber = Val(ActiveCell.Value) + 1
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

intResponse = MsgBox("Are you certain of the following:" + vbNewLine + "Product Name: " + strName + vbNewLine + "Quantity: " + CStr(intQuantity) + vbNewLine + "Price: " + CStr(intPrice), vbYesNo)

'Validating Product Name

If Not (Len(strName) = 0) Then    'Check that strName isn't empty
    If Not (IsNumeric(strName)) Then    'Check that it is not a number
        'Do Nothing - Maintain value of intResponse
    Else
        MsgBox ("Product Name should not be a number")
        intResponse = 0                 'Set intResponse to value different than vbYes
    End If
Else
    MsgBox ("Product Name is empty")
    intResponse = 0           'Set intResponse to value different than vbYes
End If

'Validating Quantity
If (intResponse = 6) Then
    If (IsNumeric(intQuantity)) Then
        If (intQuantity > 0) Then
            'Do Nothing
        Else
            MsgBox ("Quantity should be greater than zero")
            intResponse = 0          'Set intResponse to value different than vbYes
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("Quantity should be a number")
    End If
End If

'Validating Price

If (intResponse = 6) Then
    If (IsNumeric(intPrice)) Then
        If (intPrice > 0) Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            MsgBox ("Price should be greater than zero")
            intResponse = 0          'Set intResponse to value different than vbYes
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("Price should be a number")
    End If
End If



If intResponse = vbYes Then
    ActiveCell.Value = intProdNumber
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = txtProduct.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = CStr(intQuantity)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = "$" + CStr(Round(intPrice, 2))
    txtProduct.Text = ""
    txtQuantity.Text = ""
    txtPrice.Text = ""

    'Unload (frmNewProduct)
    'frmInitial.Show

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in your command button if you want, but using Textbox.change could save you time as well, for example.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("B1") = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If IsNumeric(Me.TextBox1) Then
    Else
        With Me.TextBox1
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            .SetFocus
        End With
        MsgBox "Must be a number"
    End If
    If Me.TextBox1 > 0 Then
    Else
        With Me.TextBox1
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            .SetFocus
        End With
        MsgBox "Must be  > 0"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Me.TextBox1 = Format(Me.TextBox1, "$#,##0.00")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should exit from sub or function after show message box.
Using 'Exit Sub' if you are working with Sub or using 'Exit Function' if you are working with Function.

For example

```
'Validating Price

If (intResponse = 6) Then
    If (IsNumeric(intPrice)) Then
        If (intPrice > 0) Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            MsgBox ("Price should be greater than zero")
            intResponse = 0          'Set intResponse to value different than vbYes
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("Price should be a number")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of views on the best architecture for projects, and my opinion will be only that, a personal opinion. So, FWIW, I'd handle the data validation in the `UserForm` events - that way the user doesn't go through the effort of entering all his data only to find that having clicked the "Do it" button, he's back at square one.

I imagine you have a few `TextBoxes` on your `UserForm` and some kind of "Do it" button (called "Save" or "Input" or something like that). It might be better to disable that button until all the data has been validated, so that one click is a definite *Go for launch*. In the code below there's an example of how you could do it - it paints the background of the `TextBox` green once the input is valid, but you could have messages pop up or anything you like. In terms of validation I do like `RegEx` even for numeric strings as I can easily control things like the number of decimal places for something (which can be useful for monetary values and the like). Many would disagree with that approach though.

In terms of your code, I've pasted below an example of a simpler way to acquire the product ID and populate your worksheet than selecting cells each time (avoid `Select` and `Activate` as much as possible). As `pnuts` said, be watchful of your declarations - each must have their own type identifier if you are to maintain control of your data types. In your code, for example, it looks as if you want the quanitity to be an `Integer` but it hasn't been declared as one. And in VBA, `Strings` are concatenated with `&`.

For the code below to work you would need to reference `RegEx`. Go to Tools -> References... and click the checkbox at `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`.

In your `UserForm` enter the following code, obviously changing the control names as appropriate:

```
Private Const RED As Long = &HC0C0FF
Private Const GREEN As Long = &H80FF80
Private mPriceIsValid As Boolean
Private mQuantityIsValid As Boolean
Private mProductIsValid As Boolean

Private Property Let PriceIsValid(value As Boolean)
    mPriceIsValid = value
    txtPrice.BackColor = IIf(value, GREEN, RED)
    btnProcess.Enabled = mPriceIsValid And mQuantityIsValid And mProductIsValid
End Property
Private Property Let QuantityIsValid(value As Boolean)
    mQuantityIsValid = value
    txtQuantity.BackColor = IIf(value, GREEN, RED)
    btnProcess.Enabled = mPriceIsValid And mQuantityIsValid And mProductIsValid
End Property
Private Property Let ProductIsValid(value As Boolean)
    mProductIsValid = value
    txtProduct.BackColor = IIf(value, GREEN, RED)
    btnProcess.Enabled = mPriceIsValid And mQuantityIsValid And mProductIsValid
End Property

Private Sub btnProcess_Click()
    ProcessInputs txtProduct.Text, txtQuantity.Text, txtPrice.Text
    txtProduct.Text = ""
    txtPrice.Text = ""
    txtQuantity.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub txtPrice_Change()
    If Not IsPositiveCurrency(txtPrice.Text) Then
        PriceIsValid = False
    ElseIf val(txtPrice.Text) = 0 Then
        PriceIsValid = False
    Else
        PriceIsValid = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtProduct_Change()
    ProductIsValid = (Len(txtProduct.Text) <> 0)
End Sub

Private Sub txtQuantity_Change()
    If Not IsPositiveDecimal(txtQuantity.Text, 1) Then
        QuantityIsValid = False
    ElseIf val(txtQuantity.Text) = 0 Then
        QuantityIsValid = False
    Else
        QuantityIsValid = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Function IsPositiveCurrency(textValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As New RegExp

    regex.Pattern = "^\d+(\.\d{2})?$"
    IsPositiveCurrency = regex.Test(textValue)
End Function
Private Function IsPositiveInteger(textValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As New RegExp

    regex.Pattern = "^\d+$"
    IsPositiveInteger = regex.Test(textValue)
End Function
Private Function IsPositiveDecimal(textValue As String, uptoDecPlaces As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim regex As New RegExp

    regex.Pattern = "^\d+(\.\d{1," & CStr(uptoDecPlaces) & "})?$"
    IsPositiveDecimal = regex.Test(textValue)
End Function

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ProductIsValid = False
    QuantityIsValid = False
    PriceIsValid = False
End Sub
```

Then in your `Module` paste the following code:

```
Public Sub ProcessInputs(product As String, quantity As String, price As String)
    Const PRODUCT_ID_COL As String = "A"
    Const PRODUCT_ID_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Dim wksInventory As Worksheet
    Dim nextRow As Range
    Dim id As Long
    Dim dialogResult As Integer

    dialogResult = MsgBox("Are you certain of the following:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                          "Product Name: " & product & vbCrLf & _
                          "Quantity: " & quantity & vbCrLf & _
                          "Price: " & price, vbYesNo)

    If dialogResult = vbYes Then

        'Find the next blank row
        Set wksInventory = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        Set nextRow = wksInventory.Cells(wksInventory.Rows.Count, PRODUCT_ID_COL).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        'Acquire the next product ID
        If nextRow.Row < PRODUCT_ID_FIRST_ROW Or nextRow.Row = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Headers missing!"
            End
        ElseIf nextRow.Row = PRODUCT_ID_FIRST_ROW Then
            id = 1
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(nextRow.Offset(-1).Value2) Then
            MsgBox "Product number corrupt!"
            End
        Else
            id = nextRow.Offset(-1).Value2 + 1
        End If

        'Populate and format the new row
        nextRow.Resize(, 4).value = Array(id, product, quantity, price)
        nextRow.Resize(, 4).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        nextRow.Offset(, 3).NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-[$$-409]#,##0.00 "

    End If
End Sub
```